# How to get custom value from text field in JSP?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I'm working in a very simple and small web application, it is a jsp that handles a shopping cart.

What I do at this point is to iterate through all the products that are stored in the car and add them one by one to the jsp with each iteration.

This is the code that adds a row to the jsp in each iteration:

```
            <tr>        
            <td>
                <input type=text name=Quantity value=<%=quantity%>>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type=text name=id value=<%=id%>>                 
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type=submit value="Delete" onclick=<%CustomSubmit(request,  id); %>>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

As you can see I add to the end of each row a submit type control with a custom method for handling Click events, the use of this control is to remove from the car the respective product.

The problem that I have is that when I click in the delete button of a product, the id that is passed to the CustomSubmit(...) method is not the id of the product that I'm trying to remove but the id of the last product added to the jsp.

So, my question is how can I get the correct id from the item that I'm trying to remove?

Comment: How are you iterating over each item in the cart?

Comment: I got them in an ArrayList() that is contained in a Java Bean that is located in the session scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way i use to do it is as follows:

Replace

```
<input type=submit with a button
<input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteIt('yourid');" />
```

add the deleteIt javascript function, in the function you fill a hidden input field with the id.
Then submit the page and the correct id gets passed to your page

Little sidenote its always prudent to escape all your Strings

```
dont use <input type=submit but use <input type="submit"
```

maybe like

```
  <td>
<input type="text" name="id" value="<%=id%>">
  </td>
<td>
<input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteItem('<%=id%>')">
</td>
```

Comment: Thanks for the sidenote, I will do it, now about what you suggest, I understand the javascript function part, but how do you do to get 'yourid' variable, because I{m adding rows dynamically, and I don´t know which is the id from the product that the user wants to remove, the id is contained in a column of the row, but I don't know how to get it...

Answer (score 1):

I assume your cart is a list of objects, each having the attributes id and quantity.  So I would expect you code to look something like this (noting Peter's answer about using a 'button'):

```
<input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="CustomSubmit('<%=cartItem.id%>');"/>
```

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do with the 'request' parameter in your original code but if this is the HTTP request all you will get when you try to write it to the JSP is the result of the `request.toString` method.

Comment: well, actually you can just ignore the request parameter, is not important at this moment; and it is just as you say, that is exactly how I'm working, but the problem is that when the event is fired and this code "CustomSubmit('<%=cartItem.id%>')" is executed, I don't get the "cartItem.id" from the item that I want to remove, I get the "cartItem.id" from the last item added to the jsp. One solution could be try to get the "cartItem" from the list but in order to do so I will need to know the row number of the item that I want to delete and I don't know either how to get the row number

Comment: When you look at the page source in the browser does each row in the table have the same id?  If so the problem isn't with this code, it's with either the iteration logic or the cart item object.  If not then there's something up with your JavaScript and it's time to crack out Firebug and take a look at what's going on.